# Java servlet web.xml file cannot resolve the class in the <servlet-class> tag in IntelliJ

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, servlets, web.xml

I am writing a simple web service and have put my web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder. For some reason everything in the **servlet-class** tag is coming up as **"cannot resolve class MyServlet"**. The class MyServlet is in the src folder under root directory. I cannot figure out why as to why this is happening.

```
 <web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/my/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to mark my src folder as "Source Root" in IntelliJ. This can be done by right clicking the folder -> mark directory as. After that my class files actually became linkable.